# Converting decimal to binary, any radix

Tags: java

Long-time programmer, bit-twiddler amateur.

We have an 80-bit frame (80 1's/0-s) to encode/decode for Iridium/Network communications. To get all the parameters into 80 bits (latitude, longitude, flux, etc), the alignment of the bits are not 2, 8, 16, etc. They are aligned as 3-bits, 1, 7, 8, etc. A proficient bit-twiddler in C knows about masking/shifting operations, I do not. After a couple of days of Googling, I got zip on a straight-forward example (BigInteger? String oddString = Integer.toString(number,odd_radix)? char[] Buf?). Is there a straight-forward way of doing it or a good link for me to use examples?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking here.

Comment: Sounds like conversion to octal is all you need if you're aligned to 3 bits.

Comment: He's asking how to to encode and decode arbitrary bit patterns in to/from an 80 bit (10 byte) buffer using Java.

Comment: @WillHartung: So nothing to do with "converting decimal to binary, any radix" ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Well, since both **decimal** and **binary** define specific radices... no. ;)

Comment: As I read this, this has nothing really to do with converting decimal to binary, or with any radix other than 2.  Rather, you want to assemble binary values of varying width together to comprise an 80-bit field.  This is basically a simple matter of shift-and-mask.  If you were to give us a list of the field widths someone could knock together some example code rather quickly.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite straightforward, to a point. The primary problem is that you have 80 bits and there isn't a "natural" way to represent that as a monolithic block in Java.

There's the BitSet class, but it doesn't really offer what you want (i.e. "I want the value of the 3 bits 7, 8, and 9 as an integer" or converse "set the 3 bit value starting at bit 7").

Masking and shifting are straightforward, if your representation is large enough. If your set of bits were less than 32, a simple `int` would be large enough. Unfortunately, yours is 80 bits, and even a long (which is 64 bits) is not long enough.

However, if by fluke luck (having not experience with the Iridium payloads, the payload breaks up on any reasonable boundary (i.e. there's a set of field that end on the 32 bit barrier, or the 64 bit barrier), then you could break the payload up in to separate "chunks", and then treat them individual and sets of bit fields, then the masking and shifting is easy.

The other issue is that Java doesn't have an `unsigned` data type, but this is less of an issue if you don't need to try and access the data as a whole. In the end, signed or unsigned, 32 bits is 32 bits.

Converting bytes to `ints` and `longs` is pretty simple. You'll need to search for that, but it's straightforward.

But let's say that your payload can be grossly broken up in to 48 bit container, and a 32 bit container. That means that there isn't a field that straddles the 48 bit mark. This will work for any boundary on an 8 bit mark.

Basically you would convert the 48 bit, 6 byte array in to a long.

```
long l = convertFromBytes(sixByteArrayOfData);
```

Then the shifting and masking is easy. You simply make constants that represent your fields, in binary, then convert them to hexadecimal.

So, say you want bits 15, 16, 17, 18.

In binary, that's:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000111 10000000 00000000
```

But that's only 48 bits. So, pad it out

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000111 10000000 00000000
```

Convert it to hex:

```
00 00 00 00 00 07 80 00
```

Make it a single hex constant:

```
long mask15to18 = 0x0000000000078000
```

Now you can mask it:

```
int fieldValue = l & mask15to18;
```

Then you shift it. Since we're working with the 15th bit, we shift it 15 times.

```
fieldValue = fieldValue >> 15;
```

You build up a collection of masks and shifts to pull out your fields.

To add them back, you simply shift the, mask again, and add it to your final value.

```
newValue = newValue + ((fieldValue << 15) & mask15to18)
```

You need to mask to get rid of any sign extensions, since you're not working with an unsigned value.

You do this for each field, until you have a decode and encode method that converts the payload from a 10 byte array to your java object that you can normally work with.

And it works with int, byte, longs. Just need to find points in your payload where the fields don't span 8 bit boundaries. That's what makes it easier.

Comment: Excellent answer Will... this helps clarify my problem. Also, I overlooked BitSet class, which I can use for Iridium messages that ARE aligned on 8-bit boundaries. Thanks!